# How to compare diagonal elements of precision matrix (the inverted correlation matrix)?

Tags: covariance, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse, correlation-matrix

Let $$C=\begin{pmatrix}C_{11} & C_{12}\\ C_{21} & C_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$ be a $p\times p$ correlation matrix with positive entries, where $C_{11}$ is a $q\times q$ matrix. Define $D=C^{-1}=(d_{ij})$ (the precision matrix). It seems that for $0<\gamma<1$,
$$\frac{\max\limits_{1\le i\le q} d_{ii}}{\min\limits_{q+1\le j\le p}d_{jj}}<\gamma$$ 
when elements of $C_{11}$ are all much less (depending on $\gamma$) than elements of $C_{22}$. Is this correct? If so, how to prove it?

Or, is there any other sufficient (not very restrictive) condition of the above inequality? For example, when off-diagonal elements of $C_{11}$, $C_{22}$ are all equal to $a$, $c$ respectively, and entries in $C_{12}$ and $C_{21}$ are all equal to $b$, the above inequality is then correct if $(1-c)/(1-a)<\gamma$ and that $q$, $p-q$ are large enough. The inequality also holds for matrices close to this form. However, I think this condition or matrix structure is too restrictive.

I basically only care about high-dimensional matrix $C$.